# Removing lines to texture

Tags: mesh, stl

I am trying to make this box look more realistic There are too many lines and I need to remove some without messing it up. I put this into blender using a CAD file. STL. Is there a way I can do that without having to make it from scratch? The mesh is too complicated. I need to make the top clear and the bottom a tan plastic color. I've tried limited dissolve but it took chunks of the box out. [image]

Comment: when you tried Limited Dissolve, did you tweak the parameters in the Operator box (bottom left of the 3D view)?

Comment: have you tried the decimate modifier?  that might help reduce some of the vertices

Comment: No I have not tried to tweak the parameters in the box I didn't even see one show up. I am still relatively new to Blender.

Comment: Can also try to remove doubles (M then by distance) and make quads (Alt+J). No guarantee it will work

Comment: the operator box appears on the bottom left of your 3D view when you do the X > Limited Dissolve, then as soon as you do another operation it disappears, so maybe try a new limited dissolve?